# Cannot find a way to wait for vue.js async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js

I have the following code that works when I uncomment the "return" in `fetchData` below. How can I set it up so I wait for `this.fetchData` to finish to fill items? I have tried variants of other promises, async, await, but cannot get it to actually work...

So far I set a `this.items` inside `fetchData` but I realize it's absolutely not what I want to actually do. It shows me the first X lines of my call, because of setting it this way, but all the code that is supposed to happen after the `fetchData` call is bugging, starting with trying to do `items.length`.

```
import axios from 'axios';

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            search: '',
            totalItems: 0,
            items: [],
            loading: true,
            pagination: {},
            headers: [ //some headers
            ],
            items: []
        }
    },
    watch: {
      pagination: {
        handler () {
          this.getDataFromApi()
            .then(data => {
              this.items = data.items
              this.totalItems = data.total
            })
        },
        deep: true
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      this.getDataFromApi()
        .then(data => {
          this.items = data.items
          this.totalItems = data.total
        })
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData() {
            axios.get('/api/v1/translations').then(response => {
                //console.log(response.data)
                this.items = response.data.data
            })

            //the return below is working 100%:
            //return [{id:1,key:1,lg:'en',text:'woopie'}];
        },

        getDataFromApi () {
            this.loading = true
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const { sortBy, descending, page, rowsPerPage } = this.pagination

                let items = this.fetchData()
                const total = items.length

                //some code to setup pagination and sort

                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.loading = false
                    resolve({
                    items,
                    total
                    })
                    }, 1000)
            })
        }
    },
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated answer**:

Apologies, in my original answer below I completely missed this:

> So far I set a `this.items` inside `fetchData` but I realize it's absolutely not what I want to actually do.

My answer assumed you *did* want `this.items`. Sorry about that.

To just get the info from `fetchData` without using `this.items`, use the `then` handler on the promise from `axios.get` to return a new promise (remember, `then` and `catch` return promises) that resolves with `response.data.data`:

```
fetchData() {
//  vvvvvv------------------------
    return axios.get('/api/v1/translations').then(response => {
        return response.data.data;
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    })
},
```

This can be written more succinctly:

```
fetchData() {
    return axios.get('/api/v1/translations').then(response => response.data.data);
},
```

Then, in `getDataFromApi`, use a `then` handler on that promise:

```
getDataFromApi () {
    this.loading = true
    return this.fetchData().then(items => {
        // You might use this at some stage: const { sortBy, descending, page, rowsPerPage } = this.pagination
        this.loading = false;
        return { items, total: items.length };
    });
}
```

Note that it's important that the consumer of `getDataFromApi` handles promise rejection (e.g., uses a `catch` handler on it). If you don't want the consumer to do that, don't return the promise, and use a `catch` within `getDataFromApi` instead.

---

**Original answer**:

You *return* the promise from `axios.get`:

```
fetchData() {
//  vvvvvv------------------------
    return axios.get('/api/v1/translations').then(response => {
        //console.log(response.data)
        this.items = response.data.data
    })
},
```

...and then use it rather than creating a new one in `getFromApi`:

```
getDataFromApi () {
    this.loading = true
    return this.fetchData().then(() => {
        // You might use this at some stage: const { sortBy, descending, page, rowsPerPage } = this.pagination
        this.loading = false;
        return { items: this.items, total: this.items.length };
    });
}
```

Remember that `then` (and `catch`) create new promises; there's no reason for `new Promise` if you *already* have a promise to work with. More on that part: [*What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

(Note that I'm assuming you want `this.items` on the instance for some reason. If you didn't, you'd just want to use `response.data` as the return value of your `axios.get...then` callback and use it in `getDataFromApi`.)

Comment: Ok, got the principle and got it to work! Thanks a million!

Comment: @Night: Glad that helped! I took a second look at your question and realized that I'd missed a very important sentence, so I've updated the answer above. HTH. Regards,