# VueJS - Render all components after async call API are done and all dom is load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

In website program in Vuejs, I would like display my page (with a transition) but only after that all API call (Axios and VueX) are done and all DOM (including images) is load.

I have already tested the mounted method with the nexttick inside but the render is'nt done fully at the end..

Maybe you have a idea to resolve my problem ?
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I look this post : [cannot-find-a-way-to-wait-for-vue-js-async-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46023920/cannot-find-a-way-to-wait-for-vue-js-async-function)
But it is'nt resolve my problem, I need a way to know when all call API are finish and also all DOM is load (with images).
And only after all is charged, I fade in my total page.

I create a CodeSandbox to illustrate this : [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/m7vzy7134y)

Actualy you see that the mounted appear before the finish of my simulate async API call..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find a way to wait for vue.js async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46023920/cannot-find-a-way-to-wait-for-vue-js-async-function)

Comment: Thanks for your response, after have to check your link I edited my post ;)

Comment: Do you use Vue Router in your application? You might be able to use the ["Fetching Before Navigation"](Fetching Before Navigation) part in combination with creating a new image tag for every image to wait for the data.